# How to create dynamic form using JSONSchemaField based on ID passed from the form request in Django?

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, jsonschema, python-jsonschema

The form is rendering properly if I give ID as a static value in **forms.py**, it wont render properly when I use the ID that I got from form call

**views.py**

```
def assetAddJsonView(request,pk):
    form = AssetAddjsonForm(id = pk)
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'asset_add_json.html', context)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django_jsonforms.forms import JSONSchemaField

class AssetAddjsonForm(Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.request = kwargs.pop('id')
       super(AssetAddjsonForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    type_json_schema = Types.objects.values_list('details').get(id=1)   # details contains schema object
    type_json_schema = list(type_json_schema)[0]    
    add_asset = JSONSchemaField(schema = type_json_schema, options = options)
```

Instead of passing **id=1** I want to pass the value I got in **self.request**

I referred this link
[Django app generating forms dynamically from JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54569714/django-app-generating-forms-dynamically-from-json)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found out the answer for my issue**
Here is the code that I made changes in formclass

```
def assetAddJsonView(request,pk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ids = kwargs.pop('id')
        super(AssetAddjsonForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        type_json_schema = Types.objects.values_list('details').get(id=ids)
        self.fields['add_asset'] = JSONSchemaField(schema=list(type_json_schema)[0], options = options)
```